# TypeError: cannot pickle '_mysql_connector.MySQL' object

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing

Throwing TypeError: cannot pickle '_mysql_connector.MySQL' object while running with multiprocessing map function

```py
   from multiprocessing import Pool
   THREADS_COUNT = 20
   p = Pool(THREADS_COUNT)
   raw_stats = p.map(self.GetServerData,self.data) # p.map(fun,list_data)
```

```
File "dataservice/get_client.py", line 149, in GetClientLocation
    raw_stats = p.map(self.GetServerData,self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_mysql_connector.MySQL' object
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways but didn't get the solution and finally tried with the root user and it worked